# Setting the window title of a C# Windows Universal app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to change the text in the window title of a Windows Universal app using C#.

I've got a `.cs` file with a `Page` object and another with an `Application` object.

Neither of these have a [`.title`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.title?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) property I can set either through the property explorer or through code.

I've also tried accessing `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar` but it sets colors, and has no text-like properties I can see in the autocomplete pane.

How can I set this text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Double Click 'Package.appxmanifest' in the 'Soultion Explorer':

[image]

2. Change the 'display title':

[image]

3. (optional) You can also change the test using this code:

   ```
   var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
   appView.Title = "Minesweeper Classic";
   ```

   But this *prepends* it to the display name set above.